# nth-child autoincrement with @each - SASS

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, each

Is it possible to autoincrement the value inside the nth-child? I tried with @for with no success :(

This is the code:

```
 $color1: #F700FF;
 $color2: #0074FF;
 $color3: #68FF00;
    
 $colorMap: (
    c1: $color1,
    c2: $color2,
    c3: $color3,
 );
    
 @each $key, $value in $colorMap {
    .card:nth-child(1) .card_content {
        background-color: $value;
        animation-duration: 0.5s;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
 }
```

and this is the result:

```
.card:nth-child(1) .card_content {
  background-color: #F700FF;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.card:nth-child(1) .card_content {
  background-color: #0074FF;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.card:nth-child(1) .card_content {
  background-color: #68FF00;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable that you increment

```css
 $color1: #F700FF;
 $color2: #0074FF;
 $color3: #68FF00;
    
 $colorMap: (
    c1: $color1,
    c2: $color2,
    c3: $color3,
 );
   
 $i:1; 
 @each $key, $value in $colorMap {
    .card:nth-child(#{$i}) .card_content {
        background-color: $value;
        animation-duration: 0.5s;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    $i:$i+1;
 }
```

Or use [`index()`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/list#index)

```css
 $color1: #F700FF;
 $color2: #0074FF;
 $color3: #68FF00;
    
 $colorMap: (
    c1: $color1,
    c2: $color2,
    c3: $color3,
 );
   
 @each $key, $value in $colorMap {
    .card:nth-child(#{index($colorMap, $key $value)}) .card_content {
        background-color: $value;
        animation-duration: 0.5s;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Newby question: What would it be like to do it with an @for structure? Is it better that way?

Comment: @TheJoker you are already inside a for structure with your each so you cannot add another one